# BigQueryML: Random Forest Classification

Tags: python, google-bigquery, data-science, random-forest

Hello stackoverflow community!

I recently found out that Bigquery ML does not support random forest classification models. To overcome that, I figured that I might be able to build a model with sklearn package and then use the same hyperparameters on bigqueryml. Is using the boosted tree model in bigquery the best option in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can train a random forest model using BQML's boosted tree model type, with the following parameters

1. Set BOOSTER_TYPE to GBTREE
2. Set NUM_PARALLEL_TREE to some number greater than 1
3. Set MAX_ITERATIONS to 1
4. Set LEARN_RATE to 1
5. Set one of {COLSAMPLE_BYTREE, COLSAMPLE_BYLEVEL, COLSAMPLE_BYNODE} less than 1.

Answer (score 0):

Random forest model was added to BQ ML.

```
CREATE MODEL mydataset.model1
OPTIONS(MODEL_TYPE = 'RANDOM_FOREST_CLASSIFIER')
AS SELECT * FROM mydataset.mytable;
```

Doc - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-ml/docs/reference/standard-sql/bigqueryml-syntax-create-random-forest